# Eclipse - eclipse.exe disappeared when upgrading from 4.11 to 4.12

Tags: eclipse, executable

eclipsec.exe is still there which launches a command prompt window which then launches eclipse but i used to have a desktop shortcut pointing to eclipse.exe directly and that executable vanished somehow.

Is that just how eclipse works now?  If not, is there a way to restore it without reinstalling?

Thanks

Comment: There is no change to how Eclipse starts in 4.12, there should still be an eclipse.exe

Comment: The [`eclipse.exe` can be found in this Git repository](https://git.eclipse.org/c/equinox/rt.equinox.binaries.git/tree/org.eclipse.equinox.executable/bin/win32/win32/x86_64) but it might not be just this one file missing. Is there something in the log file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up re-installing eclipse over itself in the same directory and I didn't lose any plugins or modifications to the ini file.  The EXE is back!